# Conditional Form Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, user-roles

I am mapping multiple domains to the same website and comparing the domain to a db to decide what content to display. Well, one of the domains requires form authentication across all the pages while the other sites do not. What would be the best way to conditionally apply a user role across the whole site when a certain domain is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by checking what domain I was using and if it was the domain that required authentication, if the user was not in the set user role I redirected them to the login page. I just added this to each page's "Page_Load" method.

```
if (site == 13)
        {
            if (!User.IsInRole("SomeUserRole"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx");

            }
        }
```